# Change text swap animation from hover to timed

Tags: jquery, css

I found a perfect text swap animation I want to use from codepen, only problem is it swaps the text on hover and I need it to be automatic (timed) instead, does anyone know how to go about changing it from hover based to timed?, and then adding more than 2 swappable words? Also if anyone knows any great library's for these styles of animations would be great to know looked everywhere but haven't found many good examples.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".titleWrapper").addClass("ready");

  jQuery(".titleWrapper h1").each(function() {
    var fullString;
    var characters = jQuery(this).text().split("");

    $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function(i, el) {
      if (el == " ") {
        el = "&nbsp;"
      };
      $this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");
    });

  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.titleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #292929;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-space: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

h1 span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.21, 1.47) 0s;
}

.titleWrapper.ready h1 span {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

h1.first span {
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

h1.second span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

$num: 1;
@while $num < 20 {
  h1.first span:nth-of-type(#{$num}) {
    transition-delay: 0.02s * $num;
  }
  h1.second span:nth-of-type(#{$num}) {
    transition-delay: 0.03s * $num + 0.05;
  }
  $num: $num+1;
}

.titleWrapper.ready:hover h1.first span {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.titleWrapper.ready:hover h1.second span {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titleWrapper">
  <h1 class="first">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="second">World</h1>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I added some jquery to add a class called `.hover` and remove it after some seconds, works great, only it would be great if it would repeat, so it keeps adding and removing the class after 2seconds, any help appreciated,

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        addTemporaryClass: function(className, duration) {
            var elements = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                elements.removeClass(className);
            }, duration);

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);


$("#a").parent().addTemporaryClass("hover", 2000);
```

the `id="a"` is first `<h1>` tag for the word "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? Just adjust the animation timing and the translate values if adding more words...

**EDIT**

See the `animation` property in `.titleWrapper.ready h1  span` element and I've added `@keyframes swap` for the animation. Also changed text and added more words.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".titleWrapper").addClass("ready");

  jQuery(".titleWrapper h1").each(function() {
    var fullString;
    var characters = jQuery(this).text().split("");

    $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function(i, el) {
      if (el == " ") {
        el = "&nbsp;"
      };
      $this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");
    });

  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.titleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #292929;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-space: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

h1 span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.21, 1.47) 0s;
}

.titleWrapper.ready h1  span{
  animation: swap 1.5s linear 0s infinite 
  
}

@keyframes swap {
  0%{
     transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  
  100%{
     transform: translateY(-400%);
  }
}

h1.first span {
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

h1.second span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

$num: 1;
@while $num < 20 {
  h1.first span:nth-of-type(#{$num}) {
    transition-delay: 0.02s * $num;
  }
  h1.second span:nth-of-type(#{$num}) {
    transition-delay: 0.03s * $num + 0.05;
  }
  $num: $num+1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titleWrapper">
  <h1><span>My</span></h1>
  <h1><span>Name</span></h1>
  <h1><span>Is</span></h1>
  <h1><span>AMY</span></h1>
  <h1><span>My</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to lose the animation that made it good, here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/cheripllps/pen/YpgeEd for some reason it isn't working properly on stackoverflow, should have a twist style effect into the new word and pause for a bit before changing to another one, not sure if the hover css could just be changed to timer somehow through @keyframes and animate?

Comment: Yes that's what I did, I removed the `:hover` trigger and added an `animation` property to the `span`s. As for the twisting effect, it doesn't play here in SO, not sure why tho.

Comment: Edited the explanation on my answer, too

Comment: I updated the question with what I've done so far, works perfectly but just want it to loop now, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by simulating hover and then removing it after 3s and looping after 6s, only works for 2 words so if anyone can expand on it to get it working for more would be great but this will work, only changes to CSS were changing `:hover` to `.hover`, and adding `id="a"` to one of the `h1` tags in HTML to get it to cycle hover class,

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        addTemporaryClass: function(className, duration) {
            var elements = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                elements.removeClass(className);
            }, duration);

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);



function heroLoop(){
       $("#a").parent().addTemporaryClass("hover", 3000);
       x = setTimeout("heroLoop()", 6000);
}   
heroLoop();
```